# "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource not found"

Tags: properties, jboss, wildfly, system

I am passing dbUrl through systemProperties to maven-cargo plugin with wildfly15 container. But getting the following error. Please help to understand the reason

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 17:52:06,880 ERROR [org.jboss.as.cli.CommandContext] (main) {
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "outcome" => "failed",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"system-property\" => \"dbUrl\")]' not found",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "rolled-back" => true
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] }
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] {
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "outcome" => "failed",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0216: Management resource '[(\"system-property\" => \"dbUrl\")]' not found",
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]     "rolled-back" => true
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] }
```

Comment: What does your configuration look like? It looks like you're trying to read a system property with in the configuration, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi, Yes i have tried to inject 4 system properties and 2 system properties get injected into standalone-full.xml which i have chekced  and failing in dbUrl . And also for all the system properties including the dbUrl(and exactly what is sent),following is shown while running cargo in debug mode       
try
    /system-property=property1:add(value=x)
catch
    # System property is already defined, replace it
    /system-property=property1:remove
    /system-property=property1:add(value=x)
end-try

Comment: Is the try/catch failing? You could try if/else instead https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/If-elseControlFlow.

Comment: No try catch is not failing. while it is configuring the standalone-full.xml file , it is giving the above error.

Comment: i checked that lick. But still found no solutions.

Comment: Actually i am using maven cargo plugin and while updating version from widfly 8.2 to wildfly 15.0.1 i am getting the above error. It was working fine with widfly 8.2 . But failing with 15 version.

Comment: That error message means something, looks like a CLI command, is attempting to read a system property and it's failing.

Comment: Yes .. could you please tell me what should be approach to fix this? as it was working fine with wildfly 8.2 version, failing in wildfly 15.0.1.. So it can be assumed that code is fine.. something wrong with version?

Comment: Without seeing the plugin configuration I'm not sure.